# Is it possible to combine java 7 with java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, xuggler

I want to use xuggler like here:
[java xuggler leads to fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816829/java-xuggler-leads-to-fatal-error)
But to get it to work i had to downgrade to version 7.
Now i have the problem that i want to write a programm which need to have access to java 8.

Can I combine java 7 and java 8 in that way that one class is using the old java 7 and another classes use java 8?

So I guess the enduser have to use java 8 at the end, but this is not the problem.

Comment: You can't, but there might be other ways either using xuggler with Java8 or implementing your application with the features of Java 7. However you must be more specific on the errors of xuggler you are getting or the requirements that force you to use Java8.

Comment: You are pulling at the wrong end. If xuggler is incompatible to Java 8’s JVM, send a bug report to the maintainers and just wait…

Comment: I don't understand why but i installed java7.reinstalled netbeans and than i intstall java8 (without removing java7).then i add the java 8 platform to netbeans and choose it for my project. Now it runs without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in the same instance of the JVM - you could use 2 Java processes running different versions of the JRE but that sounds like complete overkill for your use case.